# Perform user action via API

Tags: php, javascript, api, rest

I've decided that I'm going to write an API for my music site. Something that I really want is to implement REST when creating my API. If I wanted the functionality to say, play the next song via the API, how would I go about doing this?

As far as my constructed URL would go, would it be something like `API/{ID}/NextSong`, `API/{ID}/?NextSong`, or `API/{ID}?NextSong`. Or would it be something a bit different than that?

As far as the code side goes, I plan on have the web service running in PHP. I would need some sort of authentication step. What would be the best way to authenticate a user with the API? (I'd imagine that there is probably a really good online resource or something for this.)

Finally, the music player is in HTML5 and Javascript/jQuery. What's the best way to get the player to actually go to the next song using the web service? I have a nextSong() javascript function, but I'm not sure how to access it. The only thing I can think of is some sort of polling, be it AJAX long-polling, or just timed polling. Is there any other better, more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks for any help, all I really need is a push in the right direction, a lot of what I know so far is due to my experience with Microsoft's listdata.svc RESTful webservice in Sharepoint 2010. The rest of my knowledge is restricted to [this article about REST APIs in PHP](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an URL with "NextSong" in it that would mean you would have to have every users state saved on the server. If I would have a player and work with AJAX against a REST-API I would let the server just be "stupid servant" that does everything I tell it to do and let the logic be on the client side.

For example I would have a service for getting a playlist in JSON or XML format. Parse this on the client. When you listen to a song in that playlist you know where in the playlist you are and when the users or player asks for the next song the musicplayer will look in the playlist (saved in array of objects maybe a linked list where you have properties for previous song and next song?), call the service for start playing song id #####. For example API/{ID}/Play/{SongID} or API/{ID}/Song/{SongID}.

Regards

(EDIT Fixed Typo)

Comment: Just to provide a different perspective, when I build RESTful systems, it is the client that is extremely dumb and the server that is intelligent.  The server provides representations that contain links.  The client simply presents those links to the user in some way and when the user activates the link, the client calls the server.  The client has no idea what it is doing.

Comment: Let me try to understand this from both your perspectives:
  
Tobias: You say make the web service extremely transparent, so it pretty much just acts as a simple data source, and all the actions and logic are handled client-side?  
@DarrelMiller: You say make the web service extremely flexible so all the actions and logic are performed server-side, and the client pretty much just initiates a type of workflow?

Both seem to have very clear advantages and disadvantages, and I'll have to take a look at that.

Do either of you have an idea how to actually make the player play the next song?

Comment: Vap0r ofcourse I know how I would make it play the next song, but in your case I'm not sure what you have available. Do you have an constant stream of music where you want to change which file to read from on the server, or does the player start reading from a "new source" when you change track? If you would tell the server to play next song does your server know which song that is next or do you need new logic for this?

Comment: @Tobias: The server will know which song is next, it is not a constant stream of music. Javascript is what is playing the song. I guess a better question would be how I get a web service request to change something on the client side in javascript.

Comment: @Vap0r you can't change anything on the serverside with just javascript, you can only make a call to the server and ask "please play the next song" and then the server does what you ask it to do with server code (I assume you don't run a javascript server) So just add some code to the "page" API/{ID}/Song/{SongID} that start playing the next song.

Comment: @Tobias There lies the problem. I'm using HTML5, so all of the javascript is responsible for playing the song. The server doesn't really have any ability to play a song, or to initiate a play song action.